# How many elements can I dynamically create?

Tags: android

How many elements can I dynamically create?

For example how many Buttons can I create as following:

```
for (int i=0; i< Max; i++)
{
    Button mButtonArray[i] = new Button(mContext);
}
```

Comment: *How many elements can I dynamically create?* as many as you want to create

Comment: ... or the memory is full

Comment: Ok, which memory ? I mean when I create an element which memory and how should be taken into consideration, In other word, I mean how can I understand there is the max memory limitation

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will get with your code is an ANR (Application Not Responding) error and probably the operating system will directly kill the app before you can know how many Buttons have been created.

Comment: For me it is a valid response since the app that runs that code will be blocked before you can know how many buttons have been created. Do you have Android programming experience?

Comment: @ Lluis Felisart, It's clear I don't run that code, it's just a code to help you identify the point of question and it seems you misunderstood